# can sha-1 values be compared with greater than or less than inequalities

Tags: cryptography, sha1

is there any way to predict sha-1 hash values

can i say that sha-1 of 100 will be lesser than that of 1000 etc

PS:i am writing a code in which i have to compare sha1 values for greater than and less than rather than equality

Answer (score 3):

No there isn't, the outcome of a hash is supposed not to be distinguishable from random (for somebody not knowing the input of course, the input always maps 1:1 if you presume collisions cannot be generated)

Comment: Yep. See [this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8160/secure-order-preserving-hash-function) for more details.

Comment: This answer is about the practical application of a hash, which is considered perfect for this question. Beware that hashes may have a [bit of bias](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20645/is-any-group-of-bits-in-a-sha-1-hash-more-less-unique-than-another)